# Time flag error while running UI Automation on ios device

Tags: iphone, instruments, ios-ui-automation, ios5

i am trying to run Automation script with instruments on an ios 5 device but it is continuously giving error in running. it is not able to execute scripts and says fail with error. when i looked at trace then found following error message with red flag.
**#13: Time-Flag exception 
script agent signaled**

Please look at attached screen shot for more detail.[image]

Please let me know if anyone has encountered the same error and got some solution.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? I'm seeing the same error message, even in the latest Xcode 4.5 preview.

Comment: I'm starting a bounty on this. My situation is that my script sometimes runs successfuly and sometimes I get this error. I tried quitting the simulator between runs but that doesn't help.

Comment: @TomA, can you show us the script you are running?

Comment: @MichaelFrederick Nothing special. A simple example script with a few steps recorded using the Record feature.

Comment: @TomA , i still havent got any solution yet. Let me know if you guys find anything.

Comment: @vikas Did you manage to find a resolution to this?

Comment: Go to Developer section from Settings and turn on "Enable UI Automation".

Answer (score 2):

On your iPhone -- Go to Settings -> Developer ->Enable UI Automation and toggle the switch to the On position.  The error is somewhat obscure and doesn't point to the problem in this case.

[image]